# How to enable one tap signin using firebase auth method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement one-tap sign in using firebase auth and i have enabled google from the firebase auth and from the google developer console i have taken the client id and when i am trying to create a simple one-tap sign in using firebase auth and one tap. i have used firebase ui documentation https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#one-tap-sign-up code but still i am unable to see any one-tap sign in when i implement https://fir-auth-f72fb.firebaseapp.com/ then i got all the functionality but not getting one tap signin

Comment: It would help a lot if you would post some code as well. We can help then by seeing what you tried

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

let uiConfig = {
    signInOptions: [
        {
            provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            // Required to enable ID token credentials for this provider.
            // This can be obtained from the Credentials page of the Google APIs
            // console. Use the same OAuth client ID used for the Google provider
            // configured with GCIP or Firebase Auth.
            clientId: '',
            customParameters: {
                // Forces account selection even when one account
                // is available.
                prompt: 'select_account',
            },
        }
    ],
    // Enable one-tap sign-in.
    credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.GOOGLE_YOLO
};

ui.start(".helper-firebase-ui", uiConfig);
```

Create a `div` in your UI with class `helper-firebase-ui`